# NoClassDefFoundError while running on 64bit machine

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am getting the following exception while service startup on a 64bit Machine.
But the code runs fine on a 32bit machine.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init (GenericApplicationContext.java:103)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.coral.CoralApplicationContext.<init>(CoralApplicationContext.java:41)
    at org.springframework.coral.CoralApplicationContext.<init>(CoralApplicationContext.java:35)
    at org.springframework.coral.DisposableApplicationContext.<init>(DisposableApplicationContext.java:16)
    at com.amazon.coral.spring.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:85)
    at com.amazon.coral.spring.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Is everything EXACTLY the same between the two boxes?  You are using spring, maybe you have this issue if you updated versions of libraries: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?20324-NoClassDefFoundError-org-objectweb-asm-CodeVisitor

Comment: The code package versions are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you (or the libraries you use) are using native code, the underlying platform is very seldom the problem in Java programs.

From the Javadoc of `NoClassDefFoundError` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

So it was present when the code was compiled, but not anymore when you try to run it elsewhere.  The single-most typical reason for this is that the classpath is incorrectly set up, usually by not having the jar-file containing the class in question is not in the classpath.  Revise your classpath definition and rerun.

If you are unfamiliar with how the classpath works I can strongly recommend reading up on the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

99% likelihood is that you have a `CLASSPATH` environment variable on the machine where it runs, and not on the machine where it doesn't. If you're starting from a service on the latter and the command-line on the former, make that 99.9%.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JAVA_HOME environment variable. If your are using eclipse IDE, check your IDE's Java Build Path.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I'm facing. I resolved the problem by adding the following 2 jar files:

- `asm-all 2.2.3.jar`
- `cglib-nodep 2.1_3.jar`

and remove the `asm.jar` and `cglib.jar` from the machine (64bit) where I got error.

But my question is why this problem exits in that machine. I checked `CLASSPATH`, `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment varibles. But all are same in the two machine.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I'm facing. I resolved the problem by adding the following 2 jar files:

asm-all 3.3.1.jar
cglib-nodep 2.1.3.jar
and remove the asm.jar and cglib.jar in lib