# spring 4.1.6 Release build issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to set up a project using spring 4.1.6. I have tried `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer with servlet 3.0` but without any luck. I am using `websphere version 8.5.5.`

After a lot of search I found out the below post for a similar issue and I was bound to use web.xml based configuration.

[Cannot deploy Spring App to Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714642/cannot-deploy-spring-app-to-websphere)

As per the valuable suggestions I have updated the class loader property of websphere and removed the entries from web.xml after which I am facing the below error.

```html
[4/26/15 22:44:09:390 GST] 00000047 AppManagement W   ADMA0116W: Unable to start: SpringSiteEAR using: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=OICTCSPRJ15Node01,version=8.5.5.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=OICTCSPRJ15Node01Cell,spec=1.0 exception is: javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1299)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1088)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:804)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1482)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1371)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:804)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&amp;#59&#59; class=org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&amp;#40&#59;Ljava/util/Set&amp;#59&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&amp;#59&#59;&amp;#41&#59;V, pc=0
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1256)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1250)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&amp;#59&#59; class=org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&amp;#40&#59;Ljava/util/Set&amp;#59&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&amp;#59&#59;&amp;#41&#59;V, pc=0
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V, pc=0
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:235)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:192)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:388)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup(Ljava/util/Set;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V, pc=0
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    ... 81 more
```

`web.xml` contents after enabling the class loader property and removing the servlet configs.

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">
    <servlet>
        <display-name>SpringSite</display-name>
        <display-name>SpringSiteStartup</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SpringSiteStartup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>main.java.springsite.startup.SpringSiteStartup</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>secure connection</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>SSL or MSSL not required</description>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Please find the below `pom.xml` I am using

```html
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snasphot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.20100224</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Find the below `mvn dependency:tree` output for my project

```html
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 1.10.0.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.11:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:runtime - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 4.0.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.11:test - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.13.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:3.0.20100224:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- (javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am stuck with this for the last few days without any luck.

Comment: Remove the `spring-asm` dependency as that doesn't exists anymore and is at least a non-compatible version. Also check your class path with `mvn dependency:tree` to check if you really have all the 4.1.6 jars and not another version brought in through a transitive dependency. You also appear to be mixing spring security versions (next to using a snapshot build instead of a final version).

Comment: Thanks for the response. In case I remove spring-asm jar I am getting the below error :
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor`
I had added this jar as suggested here : [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887957/noclassdeffounderror-while-running-on-64bit-machine). Please suggest ..

Comment: I have modified the post. Have added the `mvn dependency:tree` o/p as well.

Comment: Which indicates that one of your libraries you are using isn't compatible with spring 4.1. You are using the spring framework bom. Instead I suggest using the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) this saves you hunting down compatible versions of frameworks.

Comment: @Deinum As suggested I have modified the `dependancyManagement` as follows but still the same issue persists. I have modified the `mvn dependency:tree` in the post as well.
`<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>`

Comment: @M. Deinum - Thanks for the suggestion. It has really helped to eliminate the tedious task of searching for versions but still I am facing the Error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor` . Have updated the post.

Comment: Build a war and post the content of the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. One tip you might want to upgrade to Spring Data JPA 1.8 instead of 1.7.

Comment: Did you try to configure class-loading in WebSphere AS? I'm using Spring 4.1.6 in IBM WAS 8.5 and, in order to make it work, I had to configure the classloader by telling WAS to use first webapp classloading and then parent classloader

Comment: Please add the web.xml and the full stack trace not a snippet. You are still mixing Spring Security versions (3.2.7 and a 4.0.1 snapshot).

Comment: M. Deinum and Angelo thanks for the suggestions I have changed the class loader properties of Websphere and now it seems to initialize the spring classes. I have uploaded full stack trace for the error along with the configurations used, after changing class loader properties and removing the xml based configurations from web.xml . Please suggest I am clueless now.

Comment: The error I am facing now is : JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys for me the issue was with the default websphere servlet container. As I was using the class loader policy of parent last websphere was loading the servlet classes after the spring webmvc classes are loaded. Hence spring while loading the starter classes was failing during the verify stage ([Details Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249)).

I have changed the "servlet" and "servlet jsp" jars scope to be "compiled" instead of "provided" for the solution to work. Find my modified dependencies below:

```html
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snasphot</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.20100224</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

You can also install the fix pack for known websphere [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599064/ibm-websphere-getting-error-for-spring-aop) in case you have AOP functionality included.

Thank you friends for helping me resolve this. The suggestions provided were really helpful.